# How to make the objects stay after dropping to another column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop, persistent

I have a drag and drop functionality on my html page. Once I drag a box from one column to another, I want that box to stay in the new column for that user. So, if the user signs in back, he should see the box in the new column.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="Drag and drop table content with JavaScript"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/><!-- "position: fixed" fix for Android 2.2+ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.css' />
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-theme.min.css' />
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css' />
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' />
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/redips-drag-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/redips-drag-source.js"></script>

      <title>Kanban Model</title>
</head>

<body style="overflow-x:hidden">
<!--Header--> 
  <div id = "header">
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="/kanbannew">Welcome</a>
      </div>
     <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="Add Card">Add Card</a></li>
      <li><a href="KanbanprojectStatus">Project Status</a></li>
      <li><a href="index">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class = "container"
    <!-- tables inside this DIV could have draggable content -->
    <div id="redips-drag" style="padding-left: 100px;padding-top: 100px;width: 988px;">
        <table id="table1" style="width: 950px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <colgroup><col width="100"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/></colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="redips-mark" style="text-align: center;">New Requests</td>
                <td class="redips-mark" style="text-align: center;">Ready to Start</td>
                <td class="redips-mark" style="text-align: center;">In Progress</td>
                <td class="redips-mark" style="text-align: center;">Ready for Review</td>
                <td class="redips-mark" style="text-align: center;">Recently Finished</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #eee">
                <td style="padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px;"></td>
                <td style="padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px;">
                    <div id="d1" class="redips-drag t1" style="background-color: burlywood;height: 106px;">Login Functionality</div>
                    <div id="d2" class="redips-drag t1" style="background-color: burlywood;height: 106px;">Welcome Page</div>
                    <div id="d3" class="redips-drag t1" style="background-color: burlywood;height: 106px;">Search Functionality</div>
                </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px;"></td>
                <td style="padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px;"></td>
                <td style="padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px;">
                <div id="d4" class="redips-drag t1" style="background-color: burlywood;height: 106px;">Search Results Page</div>    
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <table id="table3">
            <colgroup><col width="100"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/><col width="100"/></colgroup>
            <tr style="background-color: #eee">
                <td id="message" class="redips-mark" title="You can not drop here"></td>                    
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color: #eee">
                <td class="redips-trash" title="Trash" ></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div><input type="hidden" class="checkbox" onclick="toggleDragging(this)" title="Enable dragging" checked="true"/><span class="message_line"></span></div>          
      </div>
    </div>

 <!--Footer--> 
   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
    </div> <!-- container-->
   </div> <!-- navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" --> 

    <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
       </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
     </div><!-- /.modal -->

  <script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var li = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var recipient = li.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var modal = $(this)
     modal.find('.modal-title').text(recipient)
    })
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You would need to store that info somewhere... Where are you storing your user info?

Comment: I m storing my data in mysql database. But, I am not sure how to get that info after moving to a new column and store in database.